T-test for a regression in R (wheather bj is equal to a number)
I am trying to find the equivalent of a t-test in Python where you can insert a number, e.g.
reg_model.t_test('x1=5')

I found a comment saying this:
t.test(y~x1, data=data, alternative=c("two.sided"), mu=5, conf.level=0.95, var.eq=F, paired=F),

However, this doesn't take into account the other regressors.
I know I can do the calculations manually, or see the confidence intervals, e.g.
reg_model <- lm(y~x1+x2+x3, data=df)
t.stat <- t.test['x1',1]-5)/t.test['x1',2] 

I was wondering if there is maybe one command that can help, like in Python.

Looks like you are trying to reinvent the F-test for linear hypotheses.

Here are some alternatives.  Alternative (4) using glht from the multcomp package seems closest to what is described in the question. Note that the lm object, fm, defined in (1) is also used in most of the others.
F test
1) anova We can perform an F test (which is in this case is equivalent to
a t test) using anova to compare the full linear model to the one restricted
by the hypothesis.  Here we see that the p value is 0.8018 .
fm <- lm(mpg ~ drat + hp, mtcars)
fm.h <- lm(mpg ~ hp + offset(5 * drat), mtcars)
anova(fm.h, fm)
## Analysis of Variance Table
##
## Model 1: mpg ~ hp + offset(5 * drat)
## Model 2: mpg ~ drat + hp
##   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
## 1     30 292.10                           
## 2     29 291.45  1   0.64483 0.0642 0.8018 <-----

Note that an equivalent way to write fm.h using update and fm is
fm.h.2 <- update(fm, . ~ . -drat + offset( 5 * drat))

2) car::linearHypothesis An easy way to perform hypothesis tests is use linearHypothesis from the car package.  We see that the F statistic gives
the same 0.8018 p value
library(car)
linearHypothesis(fm, "drat = 5")
## Linear hypothesis test
##
## Hypothesis:
## drat = 5
##
## Model 1: restricted model
## Model 2: mpg ~ drat + hp
##
##   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
## 1     30 292.10                           
## 2     29 291.45  1   0.64483 0.0642 0.8018   <-----

t test
3) lm/summary We can use lm/summary to perform the t test for us by using an offset as shown.  Look at the p value in the rightmost column for drat and it is 0.8018 as above.
fm.off <- lm(mpg ~ drat + hp + offset(5 * drat), mtcars)
summary(fm.off)
## Call:
## lm(formula = mpg ~ drat + hp + offset(5 * drat), data = mtcars)
##
## Residuals:
##     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
## -5.0369 -2.3487 -0.6034  1.1897  7.7500 
##
## Coefficients:
##              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
## (Intercept) 10.789861   5.077752   2.125   0.0422 *  
## drat        -0.301842   1.191633  -0.253   0.8018      <-----
## hp          -0.051787   0.009293  -5.573 5.17e-06 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
##
## Residual standard error: 3.17 on 29 degrees of freedom
## Multiple R-squared:  0.5631,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.533 
## F-statistic: 18.69 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 6.097e-06

Note that an equivalentn way to write fm.off using update and fm is
fm.off.2 <- update(fm, . ~ . + offset(5 * drat))

4) multcomp::glht glht is similar to linearHypothesis except it performs a t test here.
library(multcomp)
summary(glht(fm, "drat = 5"))
##
##          Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses
##
## Fit: lm(formula = mpg ~ drat + hp, data = mtcars)
##
## Linear Hypotheses:
##           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
## drat == 5    4.698      1.192  -0.253    0.802    <-----
## (Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)

5) coef/nobs/vcov We could construct the t value (t.value) and degrees of freedom (dof) and p value from coef, nobs and vcov like this.  Compare to the values produced in (3) or (4).
dof <- nobs(fm) - length(coef(fm))
num <- abs(5 - coef(fm)[["drat"]])
den <- sqrt(diag(vcov(fm))[["drat"]])
t.value <- num / den

2 * pt(t.value, dof, lower = FALSE)
## [1] 0.8018225

or equivalently
2 * (1 - pt(t.value, dof))
## [1] 0.8018225


Thank you for such a comprehensive answer!
